# DataTable cell contains line breaks while SQL table doesn't

Tags: .net, sql-server, datatable

I've been using the same simple function to return data from SQL for years and I think this is the first time I'm experiencing this. I've checked the SQL table, copy pasted the cell into Notepad++, displayed all characters and there's only spaces between words, nothing special. The column is of type `nvarchar`. But when I retrieve the table with `DataAdapter` many of those lines break and when I copy paste those into Notepad++ it's clearly `CRLF`. See attached image. Lines 1 & 2 are from the Visual Studio Data Table Visualizer as soon as I get the table. Line 4 is straight from SQL query Result. I'm using the same query both times.

[image]

What could be the reason for this? Been looking for hours, can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: If you're using SSMS, you did enable Retain CR/LF on copy or Save, right?

Comment: @Larnu where's that?

Comment: @Larnu found it (Query - Query Options)! OMG. I think in the past it was turned on by default. Thanks!

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid -> Retain Cr/LF

Comment: Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @Charlieface YES, because now I can see the problem is indeed in the raw (SQL) data.